# Laravel Broadcasting ,I can't get the event on java script app

Tags: php, laravel, broadcast, pusher-js

I'm using pusher in my project.in console debug show the event when I want to connect to the channel in the dashboard show the Disconnection status and I don't get the event on javascript App.
js Code:

```
Echo.private(`order.${orderId}`)
    .listen('NewChat', (e) => {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
);
```

Broadcast config:

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=625***
PUSHER_APP_KEY=bcd15f3d3c6*******
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=c8e7e09d21********
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=ap2
```

bootstrap.js:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'bcd15f3d3***********',
    cluster: 'ap2',
    encrypted: false
});
```

event:

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('order.'.$this->order_id);
}
```

channel:

```
Broadcast::channel('order.{orderId}', function () {
    return true;
});
```

[console debug status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxEmu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have no real experience iwth Laravel in combination with pusher, but i see the following:

```
Broadcast::channel('order.{orderId}',
```

`{orderId}` wont be translated to an variable value. You need `{$orderId}`. Also, doing this in a single quoted string wont work because it will just print `{$orderId}`, so you need double quotes.

Try the following:

```
Broadcast::channel("order.{$orderId}",
```

Maybe this will solve your problem, maybe not.

If not, are you sure `private(order.${orderId})` is using the right Id?
Check if `return new PrivateChannel('order.'.$this->order_id);` is using the right `$this->order_id`.